# Altium - Lock bordering rectangle in schemtic

Tags: altium, schematic

I like to place a border rectangle around sub-sections of a circuit on a single sheet to clearly show each separate function of the circuit.

Problem is if I try to move something within that border I always end up dragging the rectangle itself. `Move - Send to Back` on the rectangle does not help.

Is there some way to lock this rectangle in place to prevent it from being moved without specifically trying to? (I could just draw a rectangle manually with lines and arcs but this seems a bit OTT to achieve such a simple task.)

Using AD23.

Comment: What response did you get from the many Altium support sites when you asked?

Comment: I have an expired subscription and do not receive any further support from Altium. Any specific site you can recommend?

Comment: I've heard this one is OK: https://discord.me/altium but, I find Altium to be too labour intensive, fiddly, prone to bugs and non intuitive to be of any practical use to me. TBH I don't understand why anyone uses it.

Comment: Ta, I'll check it out. What do you use?

Comment: I use KiCAD. All CAD systems have their problems but KiCAD is the best I've found (having used CADSTAR, PADs, OrCAD, Altium and Eagle previously). Symbol and footprint management is my biggest issue with KiCAD but, I can live with the quirks.